# c# Exchange web service doesn't work with a spécific mail adress

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to receive mails via Exchange API in C#, I can get informations of my account, but not for few of others accounts. I got this error :

**The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML**

here is the code :

```
    public void run()
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"xxx", @"xxx","xxx");
        service.Url = new Uri("https://www.myserver.fr/ews/exchange.asmx");
        PropertySet itemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
        view.PropertySet = itemPropertySet;
        SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120));
        FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, view);
        foreach (EmailMessage item in results)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        }
    }
    static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
    {
        // Return true if the URL is an HTTPS URL.
        return url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://");
    }
```

thanks for your attention

EDIT :

the XML string received from the srvice :

--ErrorL'autorit� de s�curit� locale ne peut pas �tre contact�e

translation : cannot contact autority of local security

So I believe that I can contact administrator's mail box (like mine), and not normal user boxes... so what can I do in my Exchange server to change that ?

Comment: I would suggest you enabled tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. The error means was it means but you have to look at the actually response eg tracing or use fiddler to see what is in the response which should tell you what may be happening

Comment: got it ! I'll edit my question with the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was an Active Directory access problem. I didn't enabled all network computers to access my user account.

What I did : Active Directory -> right click on user -> Properties -> Account -> connect to... -> all computers. And now it works fine !